# changing index of dataframe: getting attribute error

Tags: python, pandas

So I am working in Python trying to change the index of my dataframe.
Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data_file.csv", na_values=' ')
table = df['HINCP'].groupby(df['HHT'])
print(table.describe()[['mean', 'std', 'count', 'min', 'max']].sort_values('mean', ascending=False))
```

Here is the dataframe currently:

```
              mean            std    count      min        max
HHT                                                           
1.0  106790.565562  100888.917804  25495.0  -5100.0  1425000.0
5.0   79659.567376   74734.380152   1410.0      0.0   625000.0
7.0   69055.725901   63871.751863   1193.0      0.0   645000.0
2.0   64023.122122   59398.970193   1998.0      0.0   610000.0
3.0   49638.428821   48004.399101   5718.0  -5100.0   609000.0
4.0   48545.356298   60659.516163   5835.0  -5100.0   681000.0
6.0   37282.245015   44385.091076   8024.0 -11200.0   676000.0
```

I want the index values to be like this instead of the numbered 1,2,...,7:

```
Married couple household
Nonfamily household:Male 
Nonfamily household:Female 
Other family household:Male 
Other family household:Female 
Nonfamily household:Male 
Nonfamily household:Female
```

I tried using a `set_index()` as an attribute of `table`, where I set the key equal to a list of the index above that I want, but this gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

I was also wondering if there was any way to alter the HHT label at the top of the index, or will that come with changing the index values

Comment: GroupBy itself sets the index with unique values within the supplied column , Directly use the Column(s) which you want as an index

Comment: What do you mean use the Column(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["HHT", "HINC"], data = np.transpose([[2,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,4], [1,1,3,1,4,7,8,9,11]]))
>>> df
   HHT  HINC
0    2     1
1    3     1
2    2     3
3    2     1
4    2     4
5    3     7
6    3     8
7    3     9
8    4    11
>>> table = df['HINC'].groupby(df['HHT'])
>>> td = table.describe()
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(td)
>>> df2.index = ['lab1', 'lab2', 'lab3']
>>> df2
      count   mean       std   min   25%   50%    75%   max
lab1    4.0   2.25  1.500000   1.0   1.0   2.0   3.25   4.0
lab2    4.0   6.25  3.593976   1.0   5.5   7.5   8.25   9.0
lab3    1.0  11.00       NaN  11.0  11.0  11.0  11.00  11.0
```

Comment: The problem is I used groupby to create this dataframe where my csv file has 20000 rows and is grouped into the 7 above. This means I can't directly index the df right after I read it because of the length mismatch. I tried applying this index after using groupby, but I kept getting the attribute error.

Comment: what is pum_df and table1 in your example?

Comment: I edited my post to help. I renamed things to try and simplify when i was posting but it actually complicated things

Comment: Hey, I think all you have to do is change the format of your table. Check the edits of my answer